# Order matched geometries on line by distance in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometry, spatial-analysis

I want to be able to find Points near (with a given threshold) a given Line-Geometry and Polygons that it crosses.
I already have that part of the problem solved, but now I'd like to order the results. Fist match first, last match last.

Here's a sample:
[image]

My result should be something like:

```
--+-------------------------
1 | point A
2 | polygon A
3 | point B
4 | point A
```

I've tried `ST_Line_Locate_Point` which seems to do basically that, but this will only give me the closest match, right?

So my problem would be the following. My input line crosses a certain point twice. One time a bit closer on the way back e.g. a bit further away.
Is there anything build into PostGIS to help me with that? Or will I have to do the analysis of something like that on my own?

How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repeated passing of the same point is tricky, and you won't get any direct help from PostGIS.

However, you can

- create a sequenced set of minimal components (two-vertice segments) from your *LineString*s

  ```
  SELECT id,
         seq,
         geom
  FROM   (
      SELECT ln.id,
             dmp.path[1] AS seq,
             ST_MakeLine(
               dmp.geom,
               LEAD(dmp.geom) OVER(PARTITION BY ln.id ORDER BY dmp.path)
             ) AS geom
      FROM   <line_table> AS ln,
             LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(ln.geom) AS dmp
  ) q
  WHERE  geom IS NOT NULL
  ;
  ```
- find all geometries in range and `ORDER BY` the sequenced segments and the fraction of line length at which those geometries (for *Points*) or derived *Point* geometries (for *Polygons*) project onto the line segment:

  ```
  WITH
    segs AS [MATERIALIZED] (
      <above_query>
    )
  SELECT other.id
  FROM   segs
  JOIN   <other_geometries_table> AS other
    ON   ST_DWithin(segs.geom, other.geom, <threshold>)
  ORDER BY
         segs.id, segs.seq, ST_LineLocatePoint(segs.geom, other.geom)
  ;
  ```

---

The above is working on *Point*s only. You will have to derive a *Point* geometry from any crossed *Polygon* somehow; some options are to use

- the `ST_Centroid` of the *Polygon*, after determining if it is crossed
- the `ST_Centroid` of the `ST_Intersection` between *Polygon* and *LineString*

Using `ST_Centroid` has the advantage that you can pass in *Point*s, which may make streamlining the query on mixed geometry types easier, if you are indeed using a mixed geometry types table as `other`.

If not, you can `UNION ALL` queries on both tables; select all fields (including the `ST_LineLocatePoint` fraction), and `ORDER BY` in an outer query:

```
WITH
  segs AS [MATERIALIZED] (
    <above_query>
  )
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS seq,
       q.id
FROM   (
  SELECT point.id,
         segs.id AS _id,
         segs.seq AS _seq,
         ST_LineLocatePoint(segs.geom, point.geom) AS _frac
  FROM   segs
  JOIN   <point_table> AS point
    ON   ST_DWithin(segs.geom, point.geom, <threshold>)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT polygon.id,
         segs.id AS _id,
         segs.seq AS _seq,
         ST_LineLocatePoint(segs.geom, ST_Centroid(ST_Intersection(segs.geom, polygon.geom))) AS _frac
  FROM   segs
  JOIN   <polygon_table> AS polygon
    ON   ST_Crosses(segs.geom, polygon.geom)
) q
ORDER BY
       _id, _seq, _frac
;
```

---

**Note:**

This will double-count point `B` in your example! And that may or may not be intended: does the line pass point `B` twice? This is a general question of context and algorithm theory that you will encounter with this task, no matter the methodology. E.g. to exclude point `B` from getting counted twice, you'd need to add a rule to remove duplicates in adjacent segments.

Comment: Thank you so much for your super detailed answer! Really appreciate it!
As I am pretty much a Postgres and Postgis noobie...

So basically you go and split up my input line as multiple lines each containing two coordinates? Then you go and match those multiple line-segments?!? Order them and therefore I am already able to find multiple hits.

I think I need to let this sink a bit and also make some research on what `MATERIALIZED`, `LATERAL`, `PARTITION` and so on are doing, but this is an excellent starting point!

Thank you very much!

Comment: That's about the gist of it; the *LineString* gets segmentized into its components (an individual *LineString* for each consecutive pair of vertices of the original), and each of those will get analyzed for geometries in range, and their position along the segment; the rest is just ordering. You will see that the results may differ from what you expect, e.g. does the line pass point B twice? You (human) may say no, but here (algorithm), when in range of multiple segments, then yes! In fact, this is a general semantical problem you encounter with this task, no matter the methodology.